# Please find mistake in my selector code

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide an array of elements but facing problem while writing selectors for Dynamic elements,Please someone help me

```
 for(var i=0;i<Codes.length;i++)
 {
  FinQid="";
  FinQid=QID+"_"+Codes[i];
  $("'input[id^='"+FinQid+"']").hide();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input[id^='"+Codes[i]+"']").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

here:

```
$('input[id^="'+Codes[i]+'"]').hide();
```